# Python socket.connect in for loop

Tags: python, sockets, for-loop, port, port-scanning

I am writing a program in Python and a part of it is scanning for active ports on a website. in the module scanports, while if I were to say scan ports 79 to 81, I know that it should return a list with 80 in it. I know this for sure because when I run scanport it shows port 80 is up. Sorry for not having any comments:

```
import subprocess, socket, urllib2, sys
class pymap:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

################################################################################
################################################################################

    def host(self, host):
        self.host = host
        socket1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock = socket1

################################################################################
################################################################################

    def getip(self):
        if self.host == None:
            print "Specify a host first."
        else:
            return socket.gethostbyname(self.host)

################################################################################
################################################################################

    def scanports(self, start, end):
        ports = []
        self.sock.settimeout(0.000001)
        for i in xrange(start, end+1):  #49151
            try:
                self.sock.connect((self.host, i))
                ports.append(i)
            except:
                pass
        return i

################################################################################
################################################################################

    def scanport(self, port1):
        self.sock.settimeout(0.000001)
        try:
            self.sock.connect((self.host, port1))
            return 1
        except:
            return 0

################################################################################
################################################################################

    def traceroute(self):
        if self.host == None:
            print "Specify a host first."

        else:
            proc=subprocess.Popen(('tracert', self.host), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
            output=proc.communicate()[0]
            return output

################################################################################
################################################################################

    def getsource(self, url):
        page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        return page.read()

################################################################################
################################################################################

x = pymap()
x.host("www.google.com")
print x.scanports(70, 85)
print x.scanport(80)
```

EDIT:
I changed it, thanks James Henstridge for pointing out that I was using the iteration variable, otherwise it would be much harder. However, it still doesn't work:

```
    def scanports(self, start, end):
        ports = []
        self.sock.settimeout(3)
        for i in xrange(start, end+1):  #49151
            try:
                self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                self.sock.connect((self.host, port1))
                self.sock.close()
                ports.append(i)
            except:
                pass
            return ports
```

EDIT: I figured it out, it was a problem with ports.append, thanks for your help.

Comment: Your socket time out is really low. TCP is fast but I'm not so sure you're always going to complete a three way handshake in one microsecond.

Comment: I tried it at 10 seconds and it returned the same result as it does with 0.000001 seconds. Same result with scanport().

Comment: I just noticed you're not closing your socket after you're done. Usually you put that in a finally clause. Give that a try.

Comment: If you're not already familiar with them, read up on python exception handling to learn how to add a finally clause to your try statement with self.sock.close().

Comment: @marklap *"... __finally__ clause. Give that a __try__."* I see what you did there.

Comment: Unintentional but funny now that you point it out. :)

Comment: Re. the question update: you've got your return statement within the loop, which means it will only ever perform one iteration.

Comment: I took it out of the loop, it still won't work. Thanks for your help, I'm logging of now so I can't respond.

Comment: It won't help at your concrete problem, but it will make your code future-proof: instead of `self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)` and `self.sock.connect((self.host, port1))`, better use `self.sock = socket.create_connection((self.host, port1))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code:

1. Your `scanports` method is returning the loop iteration variable, so it will always return `end` no matter what ports it detects.  Perhaps you meant to return the `ports` list instead?
2. You are reusing the same socket over and over.  From the `connect` system call man page:

   > Generally, connection-based protocol sockets may successfully connect() only once

   So if you want to test multiple connection attempts, create a new socket each time.  You should also close those sockets after use.